# How can I solve this? mod_wsgi (pid=3445): Target WSGI script '/www/folder/index.py' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

How can I solve this?

```
mod_wsgi (pid=3445): Target WSGI script '/www/folder/index.py' cannot be loaded as Python module

[root@ip-172-31-8-1 www]# tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Thu Jan 11 07:57:19 2018] [error] [client 175.209.112.71]     from flask import Flask
[Thu Jan 11 07:57:19 2018] [error] [client 175.209.112.71] ImportError: No module named flask
[Thu Jan 11 07:57:20 2018] [error] [client 175.209.112.71] mod_wsgi (pid=3445): Target WSGI script '/www/folder/index.py' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://URL
[Thu Jan 11 07:57:20 2018] [error] [client 175.209.112.71] mod_wsgi (pid=3445): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/www/folder/index.py'., referer: http://URL
[Thu Jan 11 07:57:20 2018] [error] [client 175.209.112.71] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://URL
[Thu Jan 11 07:57:20 2018] [error] [client 175.209.112.71]   File "/www/folder/index.py", line 5, in <module>, referer: http://URL
[Thu Jan 11 07:57:20 2018] [error] [client 175.209.112.71]     from apps import app, referer: http://URL
[Thu Jan 11 07:57:20 2018] [error] [client 175.209.112.71]   File "/www/folder/apps/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>, referer: http://URL
[Thu Jan 11 07:57:20 2018] [error] [client 175.209.112.71]     from flask import Flask, referer: http://URL
[Thu Jan 11 07:57:20 2018] [error] [client 175.209.112.71] ImportError: No module named flask, referer: http://URL
```

Comment: What is "this"? Coudl there be any error in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You fix it by solving the errors reported in the log file.  I'd suggest starting with ensuring whatever python is being used by WSGI is the right one and that it has all the 3rd party modules that your code expects installed (hint: flask)

Answer (score 0):

Your mod_wsgi has been compiled for a different version of Python than you want to use, or you haven't configured mod_wsgi to use the Python virtual environment you have installed Flask.

For setting up a virtual environment see:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

To check what version of mod_wsgi is compiled for and using see:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use